# Finding element having &nbsp and corresponding value in selenium using python

Tags: python, selenium

I have below html code and I am trying to find element by &nbsp and corresponding text.

For example first element with class=networkColumn having     Coins has 0% in networkDataColumn.
I need to exract text of 0% for Coins
Similary I need to extract text of $100 for Ded and OOOP

How can I extract those values using find_element_by_xpath?

```
<td class="networkColumn" nowrap="nowrap" style="text-align: left;">&nbsp; &nbsp; CoIns
                    </td>
<td class="networkDataColumn">0%</td>
<td class="networkColumn" nowrap="nowrap" style="text-align: left;">&nbsp; &nbsp; Ded</td>
<td class="networkDataColumn">$100.00</td>
<td class="networkDataColumn">$95.74</td>
<td class="networkColumn" nowrap="nowrap" style="text-align: left;">&nbsp; &nbsp; OOOP
<sup>3</sup>
</td>
<td class="networkDataColumn">$100.00</td>
<td class="networkDataColumn">$95.74</td>
```

Comment: are you going to find element by value or extract it after finding it?

Answer (score 0):

```
//td[contains(text(),'Ded') and @class='networkColumn']/following::td[1]
```

You want to grab the td that contains the element than find the following td.

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[contains(text(),'Ded') and @class='networkColumn']/following::td[1]")
print(elem.text)
```

Simply grab the following td[1] and print it after getting the element that contains your text.